# How to INDEX this MySQL table for use with GEO data?

Tags: mysql, geolocation, latitude-longitude

My table currently stands like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `x_geodata` (
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `lat` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `lng` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`post_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

How do I correctly and efficiently INDEX this table?

The only query ran on this table is as follows:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['s_property_radius'])) {$dist = $_SESSION['s_property_radius'];}else{$dist = 50;}
$orig_lat = $_SESSION['s_property_address_lat'];
$orig_lon = $_SESSION['s_property_address_lng'];
$lon1 = $orig_lon - $dist / abs( cos( deg2rad( $orig_lat ) ) * 69 );
$lon2 = $orig_lon + $dist / abs( cos( deg2rad( $orig_lat ) ) * 69 );
$lat1 = $orig_lat - ( $dist / 69 );
$lat2 = $orig_lat + ( $dist / 69 );


$sql = "

SELECT `t`.`post_id`, 3956 * 2 * ASIN( SQRT( POWER( SIN( ( ".$orig_lat." - `t`.`lat` ) * pi() / 180 / 2), 2 ) + COS( ".$orig_lat." * pi() / 180) * COS( `t`.`lat` * pi() / 180 ) * POWER( SIN( ( ".$orig_lon." - `t`.`lng` ) * pi() / 180 / 2 ), 2 ) ) ) AS `distance` FROM (
    SELECT `post_id`, `lat`, `lng` FROM `x_geodata` WHERE `post_type` = 'some post type' AND `lng` BETWEEN '".$lon1."' AND '".$lon2."' AND `lat` BETWEEN '".$lat1."' AND '".$lat2."'
) AS `t` HAVING `distance` <= ".$dist."

";
```

The query checks to make sure we are looking at the correct post type and then does a square radius check on the lat and lng. The returned results are then run through a circular radius check.

What I'm looking for is updated CREATE TABLE SQL or UPDATE TABLE SQL to get this INDEXED correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Did an EXPLAIN on my query based on arnep answer and I got this:

```
id    select_type    table    type    possible_keys    key    key_len    ref    rows    Extra
1    PRIMARY    <derived2>    ALL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    3   
2    DERIVED    zch_geodatastore    range    post_type    post_type    70    NULL    3    Using where
```

No idea what it means though...

Comment: Your `EXPLAIN` has two parts: one is the outer select, the second ist the inner select. The inner select uses your new index as intended by using your `WHERE` clause, it returns 3 rows. The outer select uses this "derived" table without any index ... but don't worry: as it is calculating some stuff for every row there is no need for an index. For more information on the inner select you can do another `EXPLAIN` on it. btw: your `CREATE TABLE` uses `lon`, your `SELECT` uses `lng` ... confusing. And your inner select does not return `lat` and `lng` ... missing someting?

Comment: I've updated my code. Table should be lng not lon. I have added in `lat` and `lng` to the inner query. Don't know how I missed them when I posted this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your inner `SELECT` uses `post_type`, `lat` and `lon` in `WHERE` clause I would recommend to put an index on those.

Use `EXPLAIN [QUERY]` to see if the index is used and what benefit you get from it.

Comment: how do I put an index on these? like this: `KEY post_type (post_type,lat,lng)`?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE x_geodata ADD INDEX new_index (post_type,lat,lng);` I would recommend to use a tool like MySQL Query Browser or PHPMyAdmin to create indexes etc. and look at the created SQL output. Or read mysql.com :-)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has got special `SPATIAL` keys for MySQL.
See: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/gis-with-mysql.html

And a quote from: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html

> The MyISAM, InnoDB, NDB, and ARCHIVE storage engines support spatial columns such as (POINT and GEOMETRY. *(Section 11.17, “Spatial Extensions”, describes the spatial data types.)*

Spatial keys are:
•Available only for MyISAM tables. Specifying SPATIAL INDEX for other storage engines results in an error.
•Indexed columns must be NOT NULL.
•In MySQL 5.1, column prefix lengths are prohibited. The full width of each column is indexed.

Did you know that is a special https://gis.stackexchange.com/ forum for these kinds of questions,
I recommend you (double) post your question there as well.

Comment: Regarding posting on GIS you could say the same for http://dba.stackexchange.com/ This is a database question after all. But because this is a bit of all three I thought it more appropriate to post here. However if an admin feels the need to move this post do so.

Comment: I'm aware of using SPATIAL INDEX but isn't that a bit OTT for the simple requirement I need this table for? Plus I'd only be using POINT. Then the overhead of the spatial datatypes might be too much with all the conversion from and to a textual representation?